# Generate smallest QRCode eight in PDF with Form XObject

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, qr-code, pdfbox

What is the way to generate smallest QRCode in PDF ever?

I read that Form XObject can help to add one image and show it multiple times on pdf with different position. So considering this, how is it possible to draw a black square and positionig it correctly.

I didn’t find any lib able to do it.

Comment: What exactly is your problem *to draw a black square and positionig it correctly*? That is trivial using either of the libs you mention in your tags, [tag:itext] and [tag:pdfbox]...

Comment: I am looking a way to draw qrcode in smallest weight possible (as only one black square). I wonder if there is lib generating qrcode from text in this direction (one black square multiple position to form qrcode)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"smallest weight possible"*? (And you should fix the title of your question, there the _weight_ lost its _w_...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sort of minimal example since single pixels are best set as monochrome colour CITTFAX but HEX NIBBLES (01...EF) are much easier in a basic textual PDF for editing by hand or by application.

NOTE it is a finished working example like [image]  which can be found here https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/blob/master/demo.pdf

However, here is a cleaner hex layout suited for a stamp template. So you can change the pattern as you require and then stamp it all over the place.

Ideally the first 5 lines should be a single line but are spread here over 5 lines to make the structure clearer, so 2 x FFFFFF are lines of white as 24 bits.

NOTE because of bytes needing easy division by 8, the pixels are counted as 24 horizontal, simplified by ignoring the second guard bit on the right. Use on white sheet, but in binary 25bits would be better.

```
%PDF-1.7
%‰«Íï
1 0 obj <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>> endobj
2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>> endobj
3 0 obj <</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 144 144]/Rotate 0/Resources<</XObject<</Img0 4 0 R>>>>/Contents 5 0 R/Parent 2 0 R>> endobj
4 0 obj <</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Height 25/Width 24/BitsPerComponent 1/Length 156/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Filter/ASCIIHexDecode>>
stream
ffffff
ffffff
c06d01
df5b7d
d16f45
d15b45d17145df457dc05501fff1ff
c10cabc1ac05db5a63fdd6c7c8227d
ffd5efc04d73df60a7d15d39d14e0f
d145b7df4cc7c0415bffffffffffff>

endstream
endobj

5 0 obj
<</Length 100>>
stream
q
1 0 0 -1 18 54 cm
35 0 0 -36 0 36 cm
/Img0 Do
Q
q
1 0 0 -1 71 144 cm
70 0 0 -72 0 72 cm
/Img0 Do
Q


endstream
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000060 00000 n 
0000000111 00000 n 
0000000237 00000 n 
0000000556 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 6/Info<</Producer(SumatraPDF 3.5)>>/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
708
%%EOF
```

NOTE due to the way SO Windows and notepad handle cut and paste a pre-saved variant of above, is available for download here
https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/blob/master/qr-ansi.pdf

As single dots, it can be scaled to any size without increasing number of bytes, and generally more efficient than any SVG variant.

[image]

For comparison this page as 37x37 QRcode (even this small works with my mobile) is [image] around 300 bytes as PNG open and save instantly as PDF it's 1,115 bytes or less when decompressed (886 bytes over 2") !!, and scalable. Request as lowest resolution SVG from same web monkey, it's 64,526 bytes! There is no contest.

[image]

Comment: `As single dots, it can be scaled to any size without increasing number of bytes, and generally more efficient than any SVG variant.` Not sure about that being more efficient. I have code to produce a 37x37 qrcode in just 901 bytes using client side code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw a QRCode, you could draw each black "pixel" of a square using e.g. the rectangle method. Another option is using a line dash pattern per horizontal line (see e.g https://github.com/gettalong/hexapdf-extras/blob/master/lib/hexapdf/extras/graphic_object/qr_code.rb#L181-L198). The latter should be a bit more compact in terms of its PDF representation.

Either way provides scalable QRCodes that look good in any size.